# Angular/Ionic App Live Reload Not Updating App When Running in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic4

I can **manually** run in my Mac terminal "ionic capacitor run android" and then press the play button manually again in Android Studio to view the application with its updated code changes.

However, if I try to use "ionic capacitor run android -l" in my Mac terminal my updated application with the changed code **will not automatically load into the emulator** to view the application with its updated code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated everything to the latest CLI version? (v5)

In a recent update they changed the systems which power this over to the `native-run` package.

This has resolved issues connectivity issues with me in a similar scenario.

There are some update steps you need to follow to update your tooling and potentially your project as well which can be found here:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/develop/packages/ionic/CHANGELOG.md#lollipop-upgrading-from-cli-4

Comment: I have updated to the latest CLI version. However, this issue still is not resolved. Thank you for trying to help!